# Retrieving user login name from facebook - without login

Tags: c#, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a website and I would like retrieve a login name from facebook but without a user authentification in facebook using facebook application. Is it possible?

I've tried this: `http://graph.facebook.com/me`

This url needs an access token.

I can see this plugin from facebook - [PLUGIN](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/) - If I've tried this plugin on my website then i needn't to login on facebook and I can see my login name. Is it possible to do using javascript or in server side (ASP.NET C#) in custome solution on my website?

Comment: Are you seriously asking "how can I log into a users facebook without authenticating"?

Answer (score 0):

if you have the ID of the facebook user then you can retrieve any of the public displayed things with facebook graph. So he isn't really trying to access the facebook account just retrieve the usernames.

```
try something like this if the fields are public then you should be able to see them.
graph.facebook.com/<<ID>>?fields=id,name,username
```

Comment: I've tried graph.facebook.com/me because i haven't a user id.

Comment: the me part is only going to show you the current logged in user. You would need to have the facebook IDs. Or an authorization token. If you don't have either of these then I don't think there is a way to get the data. Otherwise it would just be a spammers paradise LOL

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this using an app access token (i.e. no user login required). Using the Facebook php sdk an app access token can be generated as follows:

require 'libs/fb/facebook.php';

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '{app_id}',
  'secret' => '{app_secret}',
));

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

echo $access_token;
```

User information can them be obtained using the following REST url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/554718794?fields=id,name,username&access_token={app_access_token}
```